# tokenhandler not called using PushPlugin cordova in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

i am developing an iOS application using cordova. the problem i am facing is that the tokenHandler is not called and hence, i am unable to get the device token. i am testing on a real iOS device and the cordova version is 2.9

my code is:

```
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"#app_id","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});      // required!
                    } else {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
```

i have added the push plugin through the command line.

what may be the issue in this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you solved this issue.

Comment: yes. check your certificate (apns as well as the developer certificate). also check whether the device is in the provisioning profile or not